# Javascript - change all classes for range of id's except 1

Tags: javascript

I have a basic image gallery that I have created. I want to highlight which image number is currently being viewed.

I have the following code which works as intended, but is very cumbersome and there must be a superior way to achieve the same!

```js
function changeImg(imgId) {
  document.getElementById('img').src = 'thumbs/' + imgId + '.jpg';
  
  if (imgId == '1') {
    document.getElementById('1').className = 'gallery-nav-link-current';
    document.getElementById('2').className = 'gallery-nav-link';
    document.getElementById('3').className = 'gallery-nav-link';
  } else if (imgId == '2') {
    document.getElementById('1').className = 'gallery-nav-link';
    document.getElementById('2').className = 'gallery-nav-link-current';
    document.getElementById('3').className = 'gallery-nav-link';
  } else if (imgId == '3') {
    document.getElementById('1').className = 'gallery-nav-link';
    document.getElementById('2').className = 'gallery-nav-link';
    document.getElementById('3').className = 'gallery-nav-link-current';
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="gallery-nav-link-current" id="1" onclick="changeImg(1)" ;>1</a>
<a href="#" class="gallery-nav-link" id="2" onclick="changeImg(2)" ;>2</a>
<a href="#" class="gallery-nav-link" id="3" onclick="changeImg(3)" ;>3</a>
<img class="gallery-img" src="thumbs/1.jpg" id="img">
```

The code I have works now, but I would like to understand and make a much less cumbersome piece of code to do the highlighting.

Any pointers gratefully appreciated.

Thanks,

Dingo Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the folliwng what we do here is set the imgId to current, and check others if not same imgId add normal class:

```
  <script>
     function changeImg(imgId) {
        document.getElementById('img').src = 'thumbs/'+imgId+'.jpg';
        document.getElementById(imgId).className = 'gallery-nav-link-current';
        for(i=1; i <= 3; i++)              
          if(imgId != i.toString())
            document.getElementById(i.toString()).className = 'gallery-nav-link';
        }
   </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this adds exactly what I wanted.

Comment: could add the shorthand if too.
 `for(i=1; i <= 3; i++)  { 
 document.getElementById(i.toString()).className = 'gallery-nav-link' + ImgId = i.toString()? "-current" : '';}`

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an array of ids which do not need to be highlighted.
2. Loop over this array to apply `gallery-nav-link` class to elements matching current array item's id.
3. apply class `gallery-nav-link-current` to the input id

Comment: Hi Dhruv! Could you show me the code to do this, unfortunately I am quite a beginner with javascript so your answer doesn't help me much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ideas to improve the code.

Since the parameter 'imgId' matches the DOM id, you can set current link without a check.

```
 document.getElementById(imgId).className = 'gallery-nav-link-current';
```

Keep track of what the current link id is in a variable - for simplicity use a global variable - and only reset that DOM element to gallery-nav-link.

So, outside you function declare

```
var lastNavLinkId = null;
```

Then, inside the changeImg function

```
if (lastNavLinkId ) {
  document.getElementById(lastNavLinkId ).className = 'gallery-nav-link';
}
lastNavLinkId = imgId;
```